# Blossom template

Tags: spring, magnolia

I created a main template in blossom module and I am able to create the pages using the template.

Problem is I am not able to see the template in configuration->Modules section.

Do I need do some more configurations for this?

Answer (score 1):

Blossom templates are registered dynamically, they do not exist in repository which is why you don't see it there. Why is it a problem?